# TabBarView prevent navigation

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following problem:

I have a page with a TapBarView in Flutter.
If the customer clicks in the TapBar on another Tap I want to show a Dialog first, like "Do you really want to leave?" with yes / no buttons.
If the customer clicks "no" the selected Tap should not change.

Is it possible? If yes ... how?

Here is the example:

```
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
     
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
     
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(),
        );
      }
    }
     
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
     
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.android), text: "Tab 1",),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.phone_iphone), text: "Tab 2"),
            ],
          ),
          title: Text('TutorialKart - TabBar & TabBarView'),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            Center( child: Text("Page 1")),
            Center( child: Text("Page 2")),
          ],
        ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: create a global variable , int pageIndex = 0;
then there a function onTap in TabBar . 
onTap : (newIndex){if(newIndex!=pageIndex)showAlertbox();}

Comment: Hi Sumar, yout code will show a popup, but it will not prevent the navigation to the other index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. First, in your `TabBar` you can add any widget, so you can put a button there and inside the `onPressed` function, you can add the alertDialog for the user:

```
 TabBar(
            labelColor: Colors.black,
            tabs: [
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('First Tab'),
                onPressed: () {
                        //logic for the AlertDialog and inside the AlertDialog you can Navigate to the other tab
                             },
              ),
              Tab(
                text: 'Second Tab',
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi, it works but it is still possible to navigate with gesture (swipe left or right)